# Asterisk MoH (музыка на удержании)

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

asterisk - 16
freepbx - 14
При звонке на входящий транк слышно как мелодия начинает воспроизводится, потом обрывается, несколько секунд тишины и далее обычные гудки, хотя данная мелодия отлично прослушивается если набрать ринг группу внутри компании.
Транк завёрнут на ринг группу, в которой стоит мой moh, при этом в свойствах inbound route moh отключён.
Есть и другие входящие маршруты для которых установлен свой moh в ринг группе, который нормально воспроизводится, пробовал ставить его и использовал дефолтный moh, но результат одинаковый, обрывается с 3 секунды примерно. В консоли астериска выводится сообщение о том что воспроизведение моего moh стартовало и дальше без ошибок, воспроизведение moh заканчивается если мы вешаем трубку не установив соединение, либо поднимаем трубку на том конце.
Подскажите как отдебажить и где смотреть предметнее. Были подозрения на нехватку внешнего канала, но я проверил это не так.

Comment: В логе во время переключения с мелодии на гудки что-то происходит?

Comment: Нет тишина, после переключает на гудки. В логах пусто.

Comment: Диалплан стандартный сгенерированный freepbx, или самописный?

Comment: Стандартный, без заморочек на custom.

Comment: В самой записи нет косяков? Если этот мох завернуть на другой входящий маршрут, играет нормально до конца?

Comment: Нормальный, если я звоню внутри компании, нормально играет.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился весьма просто. Провайдер резал медиапоток.

Comment: Возможно, перед воспроизведением медиапотока требовалось ответить на звонок (Answer) перед помещением на ринг группу?

Comment: Как то не подумал об этом. Спасибо.